# Print out full project build order in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

This is a simple question.  I need to get a complete list of the project build order for our solution.
Is there a way to get Visual Studio 2010 to print out a list of the projects in the order it will build them?
Maybe an add-in that will do it?
I'd even settle for a screen shot or series of screen shots except that from the Project Dependencies build order it would take over twenty of them since the dialog is not sizable.  What does MS have against sizable dialogs anyway?

Thanks

Comment: What about a Rebuild and copy/pasting the output window?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and yes normally that would be a workable although painful work around.  Unfortunately in our company we use third party tools in some of our projects and not every developer has a license for them, i am one without a license. so my list would be incomplete and i need the full list.

Comment: upvote for the comment on resizable dialogs in VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own just so i can mark it as answered.  Thanks to PVitt's comment, i thought of getting a full build output from our CM group and parsing it with regex to get the full list.  In 10 minutes i had both the list the projects where started building and also the order in which they finished.  Even more than I needed.
Thanks again Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Even better : reverse the `clean solution` order. The logs are usually much cleaner on a big project.